# Usage of drinki instead of trinki

Tags: word-usage

There is a verb *drinki* which means 'to drink alcohol ceremonially or for pleasure' according to [reta-vortato.de](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/drink.html#drink.0i). So there will be difference between *Ĉu vi volas trinki* meaning water or tea and *Ĉu vi volas drinki* meaning beer or wine. How easily this could be used in communication? How popular is *drinki*?

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot go wrong with the Fundamental `trink-`. `drink` is a new root with a not so clear meaning which is ok in certain environments where alcohol consumption has a social importance, but you are not **forced** to use it. Just stick to `trink` and you will be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Drinki* is usually used in the meaning "to get drunk". I wouldn't use it, when you toast to something say in a gala.

You might want to take a look at a previous discussion ["Trink-" versus "drink-"](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/trink-versus-drink)