# Kiel oni nomas la mampintojn de viroj (kiuj havas viran korpon)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ĉu ekzistas aparta vorto por la pintoj de la "mamoj" de viroj? Aŭ ĉu la sama vorto estas uzata, kvazaŭ ankaŭ viraj korpoj havus mamojn?

Answer (score 8):

Oni uzas la samajn vortojn senrilate al sekso.

- *mampinto* — nipple
- *cico* — nipple
- *cicumo* — false teat, mouthpiece, etc, resembling nipple

La vortaro de Wells asertas ke *niplo* estas "grease nipple", t.e. cicumforma valvo al kiu oni almetas grasinjektilon. Kontraŭe, PIV asertas ke *niplo* estas speco de ŝraŭbkanela juntopeco inter tuboj, t.e. "threaded nipple." Mi ne scias sufiĉe por decidi kiun sekvi; eble ambaŭ pravas.

Answer (score -3):

*Mameto* estas la vorto ke mi scias por la aĵo je la pintoj de mamoj. Mi ne scias kial ĝi ne devus uzita por ambaŭ viroj kaj virinoj.

Comment: Could you include a reference to what dictionary that's found in or examples of the word being used by a credible Esperanto author?

Comment: @Tomaso ESPDIC.

Comment: That's been discussed elsewhere on Esperanto Stack Exchange. ESPDIC is not an authoritative source, since it's purpose is to document all usage regardless of whether this usage is correct.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Can you point to such a discussion? All I found were other instances of you saying ESPDIC isn't a good source. I like ESPDIC because it is easily available in a machine readable format (from which I can create specific flashcard sets). There are occasional errors, but a word like 'mameto' uses a known root and affix, and is easily comprehensible. I'd argue that a root/affix combination better adheres to the ideals of Esperanto word creation than 2 roots. And also that there is no authoritative source. If people use a word and it is understood, then it is a word.

Comment: I was thinking primarily of this comment from Lee. I suppose it's not much of a "discussion." There's not much to discuss. As an experienced speaker, I will point out that there's more to speaking Esperanto than coming up with words which seem to make sense. *Malne* and *piedingingo* are potentially logical words (like *mameto*), but they aren't used by anybody and would receive a strange reaction. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/do-dictionaries-that-dont-exist-online-reflect-current-usage#comment1867_1948